# Multi markers messages presented in one line when hover over eclipse verticalRuler

Tags: eclipse, editor, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I'm adding markers to the vertical ruler in eclipse, by the code written below.
Problem is, that when there are several markers on the same Editor's line, their messages are presented IN ONE LINE (concatenated), in the Hover pop-up over the editor's vertical ruler.
This formatting of messages is not user friendly, since the end-user can't understand when one message ends and the other starts. In Eclipse's Java-editor, at Multi-markers on the same line in editor, the marker's messages are split to different rows in the vertical ruler hover pop-up.

How to place different markers messages in separate lines inside the verticalRuler hover pop-up, when the markers had been issued from the same line of code in my editor-line?

Thanks in advance for your help

```java
    try {
        final IMarker marker = file.createMarker(MARKER_TYPE);

        marker.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, issue.getMessage());
        marker.setAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, issue.getSeverity().ordinal());
        int lineNumber = issue.getLine();
        if (lineNumber == -1) {
            lineNumber = 1;
        }
        marker.setAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, lineNumber);
        marker.setAttribute(IMarker.LOCATION, MessageFormat.format(Messages.FILE_TYPE_PLACEHOLDER, Integer.toString(lineNumber)));
        marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_START, issue.getOffset());
        int charEnd = issue.getOffset() + issue.getLength();
        final String sourceStr = mEditor.getDocumentProvider().getDocument(mEditor.getEditorInput()).get();
        if (charEnd > sourceStr.length()) {
            charEnd = -1;
        }
        marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_END, charEnd);

    } catch (CoreException e) {
        Activator.getEditorLog().logError("Could not add marker", e); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is set up in `JavaEditor.createAnnotationRulerColumn`. This creates an `AnnotationRulerColumn` and then calls `AnnotationRulerColumn.setHover` specifying an instance of `JavaExpandHover`.

`JavaExpandHover` uses a number of JDT internal classes to construct the hover data, but these all implement standard interfaces so could be duplicated (but code is far too long to but here!)